# Add realtime time to onclick event

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, lucee

When I click a link I want to add the date/time-stamp on the moment you click on it. The timestamp must be encrypted before sending.

I found a good example:

```
  <a href="#" onClick="window.open('/download.cfm?f=#filname#&t=' + (new Date().getTime()));">click me</a>
```

But I want to encrypt the timestamp. So I have tried this, but now the timestamp is not realtime, but generated when the page is loaded.

```
 <a onClick="window.open('/download.cfm?f=#filename#&t=#encrypt(Now(), application.EncryptionKey, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "HEX")#','_system');" href="##">#filename#</a>
```

Comment: I suggest using ColdFusion's now() function to identify the date and time as one of the first lines of code in download.cfm.

Comment: Realtime to what? To your server, the user's browser, UTC, ...? And why do you need to encrypt time before sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use the javascript btoa function for a Base-64 hash and the atob function to return it back to the numeric equivalent.

```
btoa(new Date().getTime())
```

Will return something like this based on your current date/time:

```
"MTU2MzY0MTc2MzA2Mg=="
```

Use this to return the hashed value back to the numeric.

```
atob("MTU2MzY0MTc2MzA2Mg==")
```

#### UPDATE:

You could look into implementing the crypto-js libraries for better encryption, but I don't think that this is really going to solve the aspects of not altering the url with a different timestamp. Based on your example querystring, a better approach may be to implement a one-time use key.

From the CF server side, generate a "token" key that is inserted into a  database table (or other server side storage) that includes an active flag and appended the token value to the querystring.

`/download.cfm?f=#filname#&key=#token#`

Within your download.cfm file, add logic that will check the active state of the token key. If the key is active, flip the state to notactive and allow the download to occur, otherwise disallow the download.

Comment: That is a simple solution, thanks! But when I need a little bit more security? That is why I encrypt the value with a key (application.EncryptionKey)

Comment: Would you mind expanding on the level of security your wanting to achieve?

Comment: That it is not possible to alter the url, to get a different timestamp.

Comment: What happens if someone clicks the link multiple times (ie, right-click, ctrl+click, etc)?  If you ever want to increase security and use a content-security-policy (CSP) rule, it will prevent inline javascript from working.You should consider adding javascript event listeners & generating an encrypted UTC date/time value on-the-fly.